# Best way to pass index value between functions in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function

New to Swift. I am populating a series of UIViews from values in an Array. I am needing to pass the individual index values across multiple functions at diffrent states of longPress.

What is the best way way of setting?

I have found many examples, but most have to do with index.row values of UITableViews.

**EDIT:** I have included a slimmed down version of the relevant code.

```
func createBlock(title: String) -> UIView {

    let block = UIView()
    block.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
    block.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    block.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    let longPressRec = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.longPressed(_:)))
    block.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRec)

    return block

}

func longPressed(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){

    switch (sender.state) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
        startDrag(sender)
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
        dragOn(sender)
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
        stopDrag(sender)
    default:
        return
    }

}

func startDrag(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){

}

func dragOn(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){

}

func stopDrag(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){

}
```

Comment: Code please.. can't help you without code.

Comment: May you please post code?

Comment: Done. I included what I believe to be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Set the tag of the sender.

Add an extension:

```
extension UILongPressGestureRecognizer {

    var tag: Int! {
        get {
            return 0
        }
        set(newValue) {
            self.tag = newValue
        }
    }

}
```

Try this:

```
longPressRec.tag = indexPath.row
```

And then:

```
func longPressed(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    let tag = sender.tag
    //Do something with tag
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. indexPath.row? Not a table view, so it will come back as unresolved. Does the exstension have to be outside the class? Because within the class it is coming back with the error DECLARATION IS ONLY VALID AT FILE SCOPE.

Comment: Yes it has to be outside of a class. And indexPath.row is only a demonstration; you can put whatever number you want to pass on in there.

Comment: Why can I not directly callup the index value? `let passedIndex = title[index]`

Comment: I think I just relized how stupid my question is. I was preparing to setup multiple arrays to form groups, but still working with a single string.